# C invalid initializer on empty line and invalid argument on a while loop

Tags: c

I am getting those following errors in this code I am not sure what causes them. Since one of them happens on an empty line where nothing happens. The other is on a while loop that doesn't take an argument I believe.

Error message:

> test.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> test.c:28:15: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
> 28 |       checker = decrypt(Ciphertext,key,iv);
> |               ^
> test.c:31:8: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
> 31 |        printf(key);
> |        ^~~~~~
> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGWk1m2.o: in function `main':   test.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to` readWord'
> /usr/bin/ld: test.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `decrypt'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conf.h>
#include <evp.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
unsigned char *readword(FILE *fp);
int decrypt(unsigned char *Ciphertext, unsigned char *key,unsigned char *iv);
int main (void)
{

    char *key = NULL;
    char *iv = "aabbccddeeff00998877665544332211";
    char *Plaintext = "This is a top secret.";
    char *Ciphertext = "764aa26b55a4da654df6b19e4bce00f4ed05e09346fb0e762583cb7da2ac93a2";
    char *checker;
    //  invalid initializer on this line for some reason
    FILE words;
       words = (fopen("words", "r"));

    while(1) {  // invalid argument when I am not even using one? it's C standard loop right?
        key = readword(words);
        if (!key){
            printf("the key was not found");
            break;
        }
        else{
            checker = decrypt(Ciphertext,key,iv);
            if(strcmp(checker,Plaintext)){
                printf("the correct key is ");
                printf(key);
            }
            free(key);
            free(checker);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't say which errors you are getting. Also you didn't share the `.h` files that you're using. When I try to compile this code after removing the `.h` file include lines, it seems to compile "OK" (save for some type errors). So maybe one of your `.h` files contains a missing closing bracket or something. Or you forgot to hit save.

Comment: One uses a POINTER to a FILE struct returned by fopen()... The other error is because the compiler is now confused... Use `FILE *words;` and it will all be alright, I'm sure... Time to flag this question as 'typo'...

Comment: Also, I'd normally expect decryption to produce correct plaintext (and often _any_ plaintext) only with correct key, but your test `strcmp(checker,Plaintext)` is nonzero (and thus 'true' in C) only when checker (the decryption result) and Plaintext (the apparently expected value) point to strings that are NOT the same. Read the specification of, or man page for, `strcmp`.

Comment: @omer yes I did say what error message I get, I am not sure. The H files come directly from openSSL and well GCC packages I am not sure why they would bug out. Deleting the include files, bumps the error messages to break and well strcmp. line

Comment: @Fe2O3 FILE *words gets the same errors  now I have invalied initalizer on FILE *words instead and get it on the if (!key){  line instead

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 this is for finding the secret key.  But will read up on strcmp

Comment: Unrelated, if those are your OpenSSL header includes, you're not including your headers correctly. OpenSSL headers should have an include-path to the OpenSSL/include folder, which itself then has an `openssl` subfolder and all headers within that. *That* subfolder should be used with your includes; Eg. you should have `-I/path/to/opensslfldr/include` and your header includes here should read `#include <openssl/evp.h>`, `#include <openssl/err.h>` etc.  Whatever resource showed you to do it as you currently are, either you're misunderstanding it or its garbage; one of the two.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually I know that, but it's really weird if i make it openSSL/err.h I get that the file can't be found. 

IDE is eclipse, and OS is windows 11

however using an LInux virtual machine I can fix this issue. Either way the code isn't running.  I get the same error messages.

Comment: @jondoe Better to copy/paste the _exact_ complete error messages than only "invalid initializer on empty line" and the misspelled "invalid arguement on a while loop".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I did but it's strange the virtual machine (as mentioned previously) generate a bigger and more detailed error message. I have updated it now in the question.

Comment: @jondoe "I am not sure what causes them." --> `int decrypt()` returns an `int` and this code assigns that to a `char *` with `char *checker; .... checker = decrypt(Ciphertext,key,iv);`.  What is unsure about that?  Why assign an `int` to a `char *`?  What is the coding goal with that line of code?

Comment: @jondoe I only brought it up because, by improperly configuring your include path to use use `/path/to/openssldir/include/openssl` rather than `/path/to/openssldir/include`, it will break any *openssl* headers that use `<openssl/somefile.h>` in *their* own headers. That said, everything chux said is accurate, and even after addressing those, there's no way we can offer any help to the linker errors, as that is coming from your build configuration *not* linking requisite object code.

Comment: @chux I am trying to save the results of the decryption, Essentialy save the well string resulting in the attempted decryption. 

Why does this become an INT?

or do you mean the IV and the key?

Comment: @jondoe "Why does this become an INT?" --> Review `int decrypt(unsigned char *Ciphertext, unsigned char *key,unsigned char *iv);`  Is the return type of the function an  `int`?
`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It does not return an int.

Comment: @jondoe "It does not return an int." -->  the `int` that begins the line `int decrypt(unsigned char *Ciphertext, unsigned char *key,unsigned char *iv);` indicates the function returns an `int`.  What do you think that `int` there implies if not the return type?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica oh my god Isee it now how could I have done this.

Comment: Do you see what is wrong? Was it a typo? Or can you answer your own question if not a typo?

Comment: @james well, not really changing int decrypt() to char decrypt() only gives me conflicting types on the decrypt function. 

Nothing get really gets changed the error message just jump down further.  Since I am not a C programmer by raw this is just confusing for me.

Comment: Changing int decrypt() to char *decrypt() doesn't magically make it return a string. The code in the question is missing a lot of stuff (mostly called out in above comments). What exactly are you trying to do? What is the objective. I can't seem to figure it out from the code and your comments.